# redirect output to function instead then saving to files

Tags: r, bash

I have a list of data frames (list_CLUMP) in R with all the same number of columns and rows. Then I save them to files and I use them as input for a function that takes a bash script as commands. The bash script takes each file as input at --clump:

```
sapply(names(list_CLUMP), 
       function (x) write_tsv(list_CLUMP[[x]],file=paste(x, "stats.tsv", sep=".") )) 

split_and_clump <- function (gwas_file){
  reference_bed="Geno_filtered_common_allmale"
  p_thresh = 0.005
  files_out<-gsub(pattern=".stats.tsv", 
                  replacement=".clumped", 
                  x=gwas_file)
  plink_command <- paste0(
    "plink --bfile ", reference_bed,
    #    " --thin-indiv-count 100000 ",
    " --clump ", gwas_file,
    " --clump-r2 0.05 --clump-kb 500 --clump-p1 ", p_thresh,
    " --out ", files_out)
  system(plink_command)}


#### add PLINK command to PATH !!!!!

Sys.getenv("PATH")
old_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(old_path, "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
", sep = ":"))

files<-list.files(pattern = "*tsv")
lapply(files, split_and_clump)
```

I would like to pass the R list directly to the function, to the bash commands rather than saving the data frames to files and then use the files for input of the function.
Any suggestion?

Comment: `plink` requires `--clump` to be a [`Comma-delimited result files`](https://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/reference.shtml#options). Not sure if there's any other way than what you're doing now.

Comment: yeah it requires a file, I was wondering if there is any workaround, but probably not

Comment: Perhaps you could go the other way around - use a shell script that runs the R code that generate the files and write them to stdout, and pipe the results into plink. If plink cannot read from stdin and must be supplied with a file name, you could use a named pipe.

Comment: that might work, yes I was thinking about stdin and out but I did not know about how to implement in R, perhaps I do it in shell, thank you very much for the advice

Comment: You're welcome. In R you can use the functions stdout() and stdin() (see ?stdout) to get a file handle, but you need two processes  that run asynchronously - one writing to stdout and one reading from stdin. You cannot do that within a single R process. It seems to me that a shell script might indeed be the best fit here.